# max vs limit which is more effective

Tags: mysql, sql

This might be a very simple question but didn't find the perfect answer.
The query is to find the 2nd highest salary which can be done by using max and limit both..

**Using MAX**

```
 select max(salary) from table1 where 
 salary < (select max(salary) from table1);
```

**Using limit**

```
select salary from table1 where 
salary < (select max(salary) from table1)
order by salary desc
limit 1;
```

So which query will be better and less time consuming considering there are 1000's of records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use order and index the salary column..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither query is the right way to go about this. You are getting MAX(salary) from records with a salary less than MAX(salary) across all records. In other words, the second-highest salary. The way to do that is just this:

```
SELECT salary FROM table1 ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

If you really do want the max, just do

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM table1
```

There's no need for subqueries here.  Regardless, make sure you have indexed the salary column, or the query will be slow no matter how you run it.

Comment: But in general which is more efficient max or limit?? This was just an example which I considered..

Comment: If you just want to know the max value, do `MAX()` -- the server will probably treat `ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1` as equivalent to using `MAX()`, but not always, so use `MAX()`. If you need an offset, use `LIMIT`, not subqueries -- subqueries are almost always significantly slower and should be avoided when not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the first query with `MAX` would be more efficient.

The second query requires sorting of the results, which has its own overhead. And I have seen that aggregation queries are in general more efficient than *select all* queries.

Disclaimer: This is based solely upon my understanding of SQL queries, but I haven't done any benchmarking.